# Rails 4 way of editing multple records individually at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm trying to use a table to store global settings. I want the /SystemSettings/edit.html.erb to be the only view and controller, which almost works. Unfortunately, I need to edit all records at the same time. I will be using an initializer as I don't want user to create or remove settings, only edit. I'm trying to go by [this railscast `(#198)`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) but bypass the checkbox way as I also have no index/show views. It seems to be working fine, but when I go to update the form I get `undefined method 'keys' for nil:NilClass`. You can see all the code on the `sys_settings` branch of my [github repo](http://www.github.com/josephhays/meddle/tree/sys_settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it that be that simple that you use :system_settings symbol to access parameters in [controller](https://github.com/josephhays/meddle/blob/sys_settings/app/controllers/system_settings_controller.rb) and create form for "settings[]" (and not "system_settings[]" in [view](https://github.com/josephhays/meddle/blob/sys_settings/app/views/system_settings/_form.html.erb)?

```
undefined method 'keys' for nil:NilClass
```

basically says you don't have any values under params[:system_settings]. Review console messages for the rails server, it prints all incoming parameters for each request. Study what comes for the update request, how parameters are named there.

Comment: This worked! I voted up, but my rep is too low. Thanks!

Comment: I am blind, I did not see the button for that. Assumed it was another rep thing.